# Equation of movement

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, vectors

> The equation of movement of a certain particle on the plane XY is given by the equation:
> $\vec{r}=4\cos(3t)\hat{i}+4\sin(3t)\hat{j}$ m, where t is in seconds.
> Prove that the trajectory of the particle is a circumference with center at the origin (0,0) and radius r=4m.

So i did this:

Transformed the position vector to a system as such $\begin{cases} x=4\cos(3t)\\ y=3\sin(3t) \end{cases}$

Then isolated t on the first equation to get the trajectory equation in terms of x, as usual: $t=\frac{\arccos(\frac{x}{4})}{3}$

And substituted on the second equation: $y=3\sin(3(\frac{\arccos(\frac{x}{4})}{3}))$

Simplified to $y=3\sin(\arccos(\frac{x}{4}))$ and then used a triangle to simplify further and got to $y=\frac34 \sqrt{4^2-x^2}$

The problem is that the circumference is $x^2+y^2=r^2$ which isolated y is $y=\sqrt{4^2-x^2}$

Why are both not equal due to the 3/4?  Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Why did you say $y=3\sin(3t)$ and not $y=4\sin(3t)$?

Comment: oops, let me edit

Comment: oh wait, then that's it? right? because 4/4=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where did i go wrong?

You should have written $y=\color{red}4\sin(3t)$, not $y=3\sin(3t)$.

It is easy to see that $x^2+y^2=(4\cos(3t))^2+(4\sin(3t))^2=4^2(\cos(3t)^2+\sin(3t)^2)=4^2$,

which is the equation of a circle with center $(0,0)$ and radius $4$.

Comment: alright, i know now, but, if i were to correct the typo with the 4 instead of 3, i'd have gotten to y=sqrt(4^2-x^2) which results to be the same as the equation of the circunference, hence it's proved. Is this way of proving less valid than what you did, which was literally plugging x and y into the equation of the circunference, and as the LHS is the same as the right side it is proved?

Comment: I find my way simpler, but I wouldn't say yours is wrong, though you should note $y=\color{red}\pm\sqrt{4-x^2}$

Comment: hmm, why we don't consider negative case then? my thing is correct but it is only correct if we only accept the positive case, why is that?